# Angular2 : using *ngFor for multidimensional array using index

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I got this array called cats from page component:
which `console.log(this.cats);` shows me this
[image]

and i want to bind it in (not so simple) html template which is:

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let group of cats">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-2></ion-col>

        <ion-col col-4 >
            <div class="home-hexa" style="background-image: url(assets/img/hexa.png);">
                <i class="icomoon-New-icon-c"></i>
                <p>{{group[0].name}}</p>

            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
            <div class="home-hexa" style="background-image: url(assets/img/hexa.png);">
                <i class="icomoon-Tourism-icon"></i>
                <p>{{group[1].name}}</p>

            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4>
            <div class="home-hexa" style="background-image: url(assets/img/hexa.png);">
                <i class="icomoon-money-icon"></i>
                <p>{{group[2].name}}</p>

            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
            <div class="home-hexa" style="background-image: url(assets/img/hexa.png);">
                <i class="icomoon-Culture-icon"></i>
                <p>{{group[3].name}}</p>

            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
            <div class="home-hexa" style="background-image: url(assets/img/hexa.png);">
                <i class="icomoon-Sport-icon"></i>
                <p>{{group[4].name}}</p>

            </div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

for the first `{{group[0].name}}` it works well but in the others it gives me error :

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

i do this because i want to loop on every 5 values to bind them manually in ion-grid .
how to solve this?
sorry for bad english.

Comment: The 4th item in your array has only 1 item (the others have 5), so that error makes sense.

Comment: Try using two *ngFor loops rather than using hardcoded indexes. Moreover if you need the index use let i = index

Comment: o4ohel you are right , that's the problem the last array gives that error. so can you give me answer to how to check first if `group[i]` exists before using it? in html not typescript.

Comment: Use it like {{group[index_no]?.name}} . This might help

Answer (score 2):

If this is your array:

cats=[[{
    id:'1',
    image:'1',
    name:'g1'
  },
    {
      id:'1',
      image:'1',
      name:'g1'
    },
    {
      id:'1',
      image:'1',
      name:'g1'
    },
    {
      id:'1',
      image:'1',
      name:'g1'
    }],[
    {
      id:'1',
      image:'1',
      name:'f1'
    },{
      id:'1',
      image:'1',
      name:'f1'
    },{
      id:'1',
      image:'1',
      name:'f1'
    }]
  ];

Then use a nested for loop like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of cats">
  <div *ngFor="let obj of group">{{obj.name}}</div>
</div>
```

You can use this sort of a *ngFor loop as per your need to fetch values from a nested array.

Comment: as you see there is no similarity in the row. so i have to make it manually